# How to use force_feed with fetch_feed

Tags: rss

I use the exact same code from Wordpress codex here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed#Example

It works as intended with most external RSS i tried to use but for one of them i have the error

> A feed could not be found at *RSS-URL*. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.

I can't find any information on how to use force_feed with the code `$rss = fetch_feed('RSS-URL');`, and i'm 100% sure the external rss code is valid. I think the problem from the RSS is the content type which is `xml` and not `rss+xml`.

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we peek into the [`fetch_feed()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1ce9a3d80040a3bcb549a84b6006ae533448d56d/wp-includes/feed.php#L654-L698) function we see the instantiation:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
```

where the object is made accessible through the `wp_feed_options` hook via:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'wp_feed_options', array( &$feed, $url ) );
```

where `$feed` is passed by reference.

This means we can adjust that object instance through the hook, before the `$feed->init()` is called within `fetch_feed()`.

*I searched this site for examples for you and found only one [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/182551/26350) by @Firsh.* that sets `$feed->force_feed(true)` through the `wp_feed_options` hook.

Comment: Yes i finaly found a similar solution. Force feed now works but the feed still doesn't, Looks like i've to instigate deeper :)

Comment: You might check if the feed is [valid](http://validator.w3.org/feed/). Another thing that I've bumped into is trying to fetch feeds from other servers on the same network where there's a strict firewall between servers  ;-) @AurélienGrimpard

Comment: Yes the feed is valid. I fetch externals rss from a very stict server, most of them works, only the one i want to use doesn't :) Will see with sysadmin if they can think of something ...

Comment: You can check if it's accessible on your server with e.g. `curl -I http://example.tld/feed/` or with some trace tools. Best of luck ;-) @AurélienGrimpard